# How to partition orders in Cosmos DB?

Tags: database-design, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm working on an application where customers can order products and the manufacturer has to process these orders. I want to use Cosmos DB and I'm currently trying to decide how to model the data. I read the [Modeling data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data), [Modeling and partitioning - a real-world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example) and [Choosing a partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey) articles in the docs and I think I understood the concepts described there, but I'm having trouble applying them to my data model, especially what to use as partition key for the `Orders`.

The `Orders` are created by `Customers`, so I first thought the `CustomerId` would make a good partition key. This would make it easy displaying all orders belonging to a customer.
However, I also need other queries: The manufacturer needs to display all orders in a given time range (e.g. to know which orders should be delivered next week and need packaging), and in order to answer that I would need to query all partitions.

The possible solutions I came up with are:

- Accept that there are going to be some cross-partition queries.
- Skip partitioning altogether and just store all orders in a single partition. With (probably over-)estimated 10kb per document I could still store 2 million orders.
- Use the change feed to replicate all orders to another container partitioned by (e.g.) month. That way only one or two partitions would need to be searched most of the time, but using a date-based partition key is generally discouraged. I don't think there will be enough orders to create any hot partitions in my case though.
- Don't use Cosmos DB for storing orders. Queries like described above would be easy to answer with a relational database. However, I do like the possibility to store all relevant order data like the products, amounts, prices etc in one document. That would be a lot more complicated in a relational database.

I'm aware that this application is probably small enough that either approach would work, but I'm still trying to do it "right" conceptually and I want to use this project to learn and be prepared for bigger ones, so any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: How about split data by customer and manufacturer? As you said, we can't achieve both goal because the two queries are stand in different direction.

Comment: Even if you can't satisfy every query making sure that it can take a large number of different values is important to split the data across multiple logical partitions.

Comment: @TinyWang There's only one manufacturer.

Comment: Are Orders the only data in the system? Usually there are some other entities, so partitioning on an item's entity type could divide things up a bit. That doesn't prevent Orders from growing large, but you could implement an archiving process that moves them out after some age to an archive container partitioned by date or id.